# I used dd command to burn the iso file of windows10 but the usb has not been detected in BIOS

Tags: usb, bios, iso-image, dd, burning

I use linux OS.

I downloaded the iso file of win10 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

And burned it to the usb using

```
sudo dd if=Win10_21H1_English_x64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1024k status=progress
```

And the burn process was succeeded and got the below configuration.

[image]

And I went to the bios display and attempted to locate the usb but not found.

What should I do for next?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by platform?

Comment: Ah, I think I got. I'll try ```sudo dmidecode -s```

Comment: I mean what OS are you trying to do this from? Doing it 'the hard way' only makes sense if you're not on Windows, otherwise MS make a tool to do it for you - go to this from a Windows computer [otherwise you get directed away from it again] - https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10

Comment: Ah ,I use linux OS.

Comment: Just copying an ISO image to an USB stick does not make it bootable.

Comment: OK - you ought to mention that in your question. Wish you luck, idk how to do it in nix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Windows ISO image from Linux to a USB stick](https://superuser.com/questions/570168/a-windows-iso-image-from-linux-to-a-usb-stick)

Comment: See also [How can I install Windows 10 on my spare hard drive](https://superuser.com/q/1606962/194694)

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you. I will try WoeUSB firstly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a linux user and want to burn a win10 iso file to a usb, use woeusb instead of using dd command.

```
sudo apt install git p7zip-full python3-pip python3-wxgtk4.0

sudo pip3 install WoeUSB-ng
```

Comment: USB is a bus, not a device or medium.  You are probably referring to a USB flash drive.  There is no chemical reaction when writing to a USB flash drive, so calling it *"burning"* is a misnomer.

Comment: I see. I use "usb flash drive" from now. And what is the correct expression instead of  "burn" ? install?

Comment: *"what is the correct expression instead of "burn" ?"* -- You'll probably always be correct with the verb "write".  "Transfer" and "copy" are also accurate for writing (binary) images; by "image" I don't mean a photo or picture, but a file only used exactly as-is.  "Store" can do when writing to a storage device.  "Install" usually implies more than a simple write, e.g. data could be customized before writing and/or multiple/selected entities are involved.

Comment: I see. Helpful info.